# How to reinitialize selectize for dynamically added select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using selectize single dropdown for my project but and on click of "Add another question" button, Selectize dropdown got added but doesn't initialize.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="clone-ques">
    <select id="" name="question" class="demo-default select-question" style="width:90%; float:left;" placeholder="Choose from our list of frequently asked questions or enter your own ">
        <option value="4">How many projects do you want?</option>
        <option value="1">Do you know programming as well?</option>
        <option value="3">This is your next question, answer it.</option>
        <option value="5">Please add more question</option>
    </select></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-attach add-ques"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Another Question</button>
```

#### Jquery:

```
    $(function() {
      var scntDiv = $('#clone-ques');
      $('.add-ques').on('click', function() {
      $('<select id="" name="question" class="demo-default select-question " style="width:90%; float:left;" placeholder="Choose from our list of frequently asked questions or enter your own ">                        <option value="4">How many projects do you want?</option><option value="1">Do you know programming as well?</option><option value="3">This is your next question, answer it.</option><option value="5">Please add more question</option></select>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                return false;
       });
 });
```

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't initialize"? What do you want when it creates?

Comment: This does seem to work without problems:
https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gwana/

Comment: This isn't selectize. This is default HTML select with options

Comment: Please make fiddle of your code.